# IIS URL Rewrite - ignore if URL contains

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, webforms

I have the following URL rewrite setup inside web.config working as I would like.

```
<rule name="Product Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^products/([^$]+)/([^$]+)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="products?durl={R:1}&amp;purl={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

Now I need to exclude any URLs that contain or end with **/action/edit** i.e. **products/action/edit**

I understand that I will need a conditions block, but I am not sure what to write.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a condition like below, negate true ensures it matches everything except action/edit

```
<conditions>
 <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="action/edit" />
</conditions>
```